Is it possible that $E(E(Y|\mathcal{F}_S)|\mathcal{F}_T) $ is not $\mathcal{F}_{S \wedge T}$-measurable?
Assume you have a filtered probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{A},P)$, two stopping-times S, T, and an integrable random variable $Y$.
In this post and answer:
Conditional Expectation based on Stopping Times
it is shown that $E(E(Y|\mathcal{F}_S)|\mathcal{F}_T) = E(Y|\mathcal{F}_{S \wedge T})$ a.s.
It is also shown in this post:
Tower Property for Expectations and Stopping Times
If the filtration is augmented or completed we then have that $E(E(Y|\mathcal{F}_S)|\mathcal{F}_T)$ is  $\mathcal{F}_{S \wedge T}$-measurable. But I am wondering, if we do not have that the filtration is complete or augmented, is it possible that that $E(E(Y|\mathcal{F}_S)|\mathcal{F}_T) $ is not $\mathcal{F}_{S \wedge T}$-measurable?
Motivation behind the quesiton.
The motivation behind this question is Jacod and Protters "Probability Essentials" exercise 24.11 showing that  $E(E(Y|\mathcal{F}_S)|\mathcal{F}_T) = E(E(Y|\mathcal{F}_T)|\mathcal{F}_S)=E(Y|\mathcal{F}_{S \wedge T})$. And  the OP in Conditional Expectation based on Stopping Times tries to show this based on the definition of conditional expectation, but is not able to show the measurability part. In the answer the a.s. equality is shown, but not the measurability part.
And if the claim I am asking about is true, then it seems is not possible to solve the exercise using the definition of conditional expectation.

Is anyone else seeing boxes in this post?  I load the page and it says $(\Omega, A, P)$ and then changes the $A$ to a box.

@Michael Sorry to hear that, it works for me in Edge and Firefox.

I used the following to fix my rendering problem (I had recently updated my Google chrome on mac, the "right-click, math settings, math renderer, SVG" fixed it): https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35669/chrome-doesnt-display-some-symbols


I am wondering, if we do not have that the filtration is complete or augmented, is it possible that that $E(E(Y|\mathcal{F}_S)|\mathcal{F}_T) $ is not $\mathcal{F}_{S \wedge T}$-measurable?

Yes and no. The conditional expectation $\mathrm E(\mathrm E(Y\mid \mathcal F_S)\mid \mathcal F_T)$ is not a random variable, but an equivalence class modulo negligible events from $\mathcal F_T$. Some elements of this class (for example, $\mathrm E(Y\mid \mathcal F_{S\wedge T})$) are $\mathcal F_{S\wedge T}$-measurable. But there may be non-measurable elements. This will be the case when $\mathcal F_{T}$ contains negligible events, which do not belong to $\mathcal F_{S\wedge T}$ (it is easy to construct an example of this happening).
